# JPA/Hibernate: Multiple unnecessary entires in a table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, database-normalization

I'm new here and I'm also new in JPA! I developed a little JPA Application with the following entities:

A Customer(Name, Prename, ID) has got an Address(ZIP_Code, city, ID). The relation between these entities is ManyToOne (Customer's perpective) and OneToMany (Address' perspective).

The code (parts) are the following: (without getters/setters)

```
@Entity
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String city;    
private int zipCode;


@Column
@ElementCollection(targetClass=CustomerEntity.class)
private List<CustomerEntity> customers;


public AddressEntity() {}


@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy="addressentity")
public List<CustomerEntity> getCustomers() {
    return customers;
}



@Entity
public class CustomerEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int primaryKey;

private String preName, surName;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=AddressEntity.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="Address_ID")
private AddressEntity address;

public CustomerEntity() {}
```

}

Now i want to add two persons:
1) Bart Simpson 1234 Springfield
2) Homer Simpson 1234 Springfield

The problem is that in the address table Springfield appears twice. But that's not the sense of normalized database! How can I realize that an AddressEntity is only added when it does not exists before!

Thanks for answering,
eniac

Comment: There is probably a better way, but try to persist the address first, then add it to the 2 users and persist those. In order to do that you'd have to remove or change the `CascadeType.ALL` in your `CustomerEntity` to something else (`CascadeType.REFRESH` would probably do). Using ALL seems a bit odd anyway mainly because in your current code, deleting a Customer will get rid of the Address that might be assigned to another user.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But the way you described has got the same effect as before

Comment: Some of these issues depend on the attachedness of the entities you're dealing with, can you add an extract of the code where you're persisting these entities?

Answer (score 0):

**Persisting new addresses**

It is possible to have many `AddressEntities` with the same `City` and `Zipcode`. If you require that a given `CustomerEntity` is related to the same `address`, then you must use that *specific* entity. So use the same `AddressEntity` that you used for Bart for Homer also

```
CustomerEntity bart = new CustomerEntity();
//Set Barts’s fields.
CustomerEntity homer = new CustomerEntity();
//Set Homers’s fields.


AddressEntity simpsonsPlace = new AddressEntity();
//set 1234 and Springfield.

bart.setAdress(simpsonsPlace);
homer.setAdress(simpsonsPlace);

List<CustomerEntity> simpsons = new ArrayList<CustomerEntity>();
simpsons.add(bart);
simpsons.add(homer);
simpsonsPlace.setCustomers(simpsons);

yourEntityManager.persist(bart);
yourEntityManager.persist(homer);
```

**Associating with existing addresses.**

If you are creating homer sometime after bart then you will want to associate bart to an existing `address`. It maybe that you will pass in the `address` from the client. This will have the id field populated and will be a *detached* entity. You can use this entity with the `em.merge()` operation;

```
CustomerEntity homer = new CustomerEntity();
homer.setAdress(detachedAddress);
yourEntityManager.merge(homer);
```

A better way might be to form a compound PK of Zip/HouseNumber for example. This ensures that any `AddressEntity` with Zip/HouseNumber combination already in the DB will be treated as a detached object, and will of course only appear once in the DB.

**Embeddables**

You have both `@ElementCollection` and `@OneToMany` targeted to your CustomerEntity *Entity*.

As per JPA Spec 11.1.14;

> The ElementCollection annotation defines a collection of instances of
>   a basic type or embeddable class.

It is therefore incorrect to target an entity with `@ElementCollection`.

You require a relation between your two entities, therefore, in you your `AddressEntity` you just need to use the `@OneToMany` and drop the `@ElementCollection`. You also need to map (with `mappedBy`) to the field of the target class and not the target class itself;

```
@Entity
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String city;    
private int zipCode;


@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy="address") //Not addressentity
private List<CustomerEntity> customers;


public AddressEntity() {}

public List<CustomerEntity> getCustomers() {
    return customers;
}
```

Alternatively you can define your CustomerEntity as an `@Embeddable` and not an `@entity`. In this way you can use `@ElementCollection` to target `CustomerEntity` from `AddressEntity`, but `CustomerEntity` would not be an entity in its own right and cannot be processed independently as it is dependent on `AddressEntity`

Comment: Thx for your answer. Droping @ElementCollection and choosing your way of annoations do not solve the problem

Comment: @Eniac - see updates, your address entities are different entities and will be persisted twice, you need to ensure you are associating Customers with the SAME addressEntity when this in fact intended as the same address.